# Is it possible to have pages in mapbook link to different data frames on 1 layout page in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I am trying to create a map series of approximately 80 sheets, but I need to have 2 sheets per layout page. Basically, I need to know if there is a way to have the pages in the map series go to different data frames inside my map?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What are you using? If you're using ArcMap 10, are you using Data Driven Pages or MPS Atlas?

If you're using Data Driven Pages (which is core functionality of ArcMap10), you are out of luck. Data Driven Pages only allows for one data frame to update dynamically with the current page. It is explained at the [ArcGIS10 Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_Data_Driven_Pages/00sr00000007000000/). Read the Detail Data Frame section. Also, the ArcGIS 10 help within ArcMap specifically says that only one data frame can be linked.

If you're using the MPS Atlas extension (on 9.3 or 10) you can have your mapbook link to different data frames through the Data Frame Manager in the MPS Atlas toolbox. To my knowledge, MPS Atlas is what you'll need to solve your problem.

To have 2 sheets per layout page (and if you want to avoid using scripts), you'll most likely need the *[Production Mapping toolset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//010300000214000000.htm) (which includes MPS Atlas). It provides a large degree of cartographic customization. Much of it you likely won't need, but it is essential if you want anything greater than the basic mapbook functionality in ArcMap 10.

*If you're using ArcMap 9.3, it is called PLTS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have said - I'm using version 9.3 with the mapbook extension. I appreciate the reply and the info!

Thanks

Comment: Cool. So you're using MPS Atlas then. The answer to your question is yes, you can have multiple linked data frames within one page in the map book. The only downside is that they all must be linked to the same feature class. When you change pages, all linked data frames will focus on the same thing. This can be set up in the Data Frame Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronise (link) data frame extents in ArcMap

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14238

Supports 2 Pages/Data Frames linked together

Note:that this script applies the rectangular extent of the active data frame to the target data frame, which may result in slight discrepancies in the viewable area if the data frames are different shapes, or if the coordinate systems are not the same.

Comment: thanks for the info. Not sure if this will do what I need, as I need to data frames for 2 different locations on the same page. I'll look into this more to see if I can use it. 

Thanks for the info.